# aes encryption getting issue with when trying to encrypt username , Bad state: AES engine not initialised

Tags: flutter, dart, aes, cryptojs, pointycastle

below here Aes encryption code logic.

```
static String encryptAESGCM(String plaintext, String key) {
    try {
      final keyBytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(key));
      final nonce = generateNonce();

      final cipher = GCMBlockCipher(AESEngine());
      final params = AEADParameters(KeyParameter(keyBytes), 128, nonce, Uint8List(0));
      cipher.init(true, params); // Initialize for encryption

      final plaintextBytes = utf8.encode(plaintext);
      final ciphertextBytes = cipher.process(Uint8List.fromList(plaintextBytes)); // Process all data at once

      return base64.encode(ciphertextBytes); // Base64 encode for transmission
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle encryption errors gracefully
      print("Encryption error: $error");
      return ""; // Or return a suitable error message
    }
  }
```

```
static Uint8List generateNonce() {
    final random = FortunaRandom(); // Or any other CSPRNG
    return random.nextBytes(12); // 12 bytes for AES-GCM
  }
```

here in this function generateNonce() , i am getting error
Bad state: AES engine not initialised what's the issue in this code

i am trying to encrypt my username & password using aes encryption, but i am getting this issue
Bad state: AES engine not initialised. what is the error in my code i am new to this please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cryptographically secure random numbers, a *cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator* (CSPRNG) is required.

[`Random.secure()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.4/dart-math/Random/Random.secure.html) from the *dart.math* library provides such a CSPRNG which automatically uses a cryptographically secure source (if none is available, an exception is thrown).
But be careful not to confuse this with [`Random()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.4/dart-math/Random/Random.html), which only provides a PRNG that is not cryptographically secure.

Alternatively, there is the class [`SecureRandom`](https://pub.dev/documentation/pointycastle/latest/api/SecureRandom-class.html) from PointyCastle, for which [`FortunaRandom`](https://pub.dev/documentation/pointycastle/latest/impl.secure_random.fortuna_random/FortunaRandom-class.html) is a possible implementation of the [*Fortuna*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG)) algorithm (among other algorithms), which must be explicitly seeded with some entropy.
This is what you use, but you forget the seed, which leads to the exception. Typically the seed is generated with `Random.secure()`.
One advantage of `SecureRandom` over (the poorly specified) `Random.secure()` is that it is more transparent and can be used more flexibly, as algorithm and seed can be controlled.

Below are sample implementations for all three cases:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';

...

// FortunaRandom()     cryptographically secure
SecureRandom secureRandom = getSecureRandom();
Uint8List data1 = secureRandom.nextBytes(12);

// Random.secure()     cryptographically secure
Uint8List data2 = generateSecureRandomData(12);

// Random()            not cryptographically secure !!!
Uint8List data3 = generateNonSecureRandomData(12);

...

SecureRandom getSecureRandom() {
  List<int> seed = List<int>.generate(32, (_) => Random.secure().nextInt(256));
  return FortunaRandom()..seed(KeyParameter(Uint8List.fromList(seed))); // cryptographically secure
}

Uint8List generateSecureRandomData(size) {
  return Uint8List.fromList(List<int>.generate(size, (_) => Random.secure().nextInt(256))); // cryptographically secure
}

Uint8List generateNonSecureRandomData(size) {
  return Uint8List.fromList(List<int>.generate(size, (_) => Random().nextInt(256))); // not cryptographically secure!!!
}
```

Comment: @ Topaco any issue on my current dart code compared to c# code

Comment: thanks Bad state: AES engine not initialised issue fixed. but still i can't login to server may be some issue in my encryption logic , i have pasted the alternative encryption logic in server side can you check that

Comment: @NinteenFive - Your original question was what caused the message *Bad state: AES engine not initialized*. I have answered this. Please ask your new question in a new post and roll this one back. Changing a question after it is answered makes it difficult for future readers to understand the problem.

Comment: ok will add new question for this

Comment: will rollback this question